# SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ok so i coded in a news section and everytime i insert new news,its shows below the old one.
i want to make it ORDER BY id but make it start like backwards.i dont know how to explain but yeh
i want them to be ordered by the newest added by the id so if the 1st row that was inserted's id is 1 then i want it to show below the next id.

so row with id = 2 will be here

so row with id = 1 will be here

thats how i want it to be, instead of it being like this

so row with id = 1 will be here

so row with id = 2 will be here

.

Sorry for my bad explanation i hope this is understandable

heres my code so far

```
<?php  
require("include/config.php");
$sqlnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlnews)) {
    $dbdate = $row['date'];
    $dbnews = $row['news'];
    echo "<h1><strong>$dbdate</strong></h1>";
    echo "<div class='content'>$dbnews</div><br><br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

add `DESC` in your `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC
```

by default, it is in `ASC` mode.

Comment: `DESC` = Descending (going from higher to lower). `ASC` = Ascending (going up, from lower to higher).

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC`

DESC is the descending keyword 
 ASC is ascending

If you specify neither then default behaviour is ascending

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DESC` keyword in your sql query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sqlnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
```

However, it isn't really such a good idea to use id, because semantically, there is nothing preventing somebody from changing the sequence which counts up automatically assigning the ID.

Therefore, you should add a column `created_at`. Everytime you insert a row, you can use the SQL function `NOW()`.

The advantage is that you can say:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE created_at <= NOW() ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

This means that you can schedule news items ahead of time, and it will automatically display when the date/time arrives!

Answer (score 0):

```
   $sqlnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

just have to add

```
order by id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code by this code:

```
<?php  
require("include/config.php");
$sqlnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlnews)) {
    $dbdate = $row['date'];
    $dbnews = $row['news'];
    echo "<h1><strong>$dbdate</strong></h1>";
    echo "<div class='content'>$dbnews</div><br><br>";
}
?>
```